# ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_AutoComplete

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, jquery-autocomplete

How can I get the javascript code generated wehen using ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_AutoComplete
 class?

```
    $item = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_AutoComplete('item', array(
        'label' => 'Item' , 
        'id' => 'auto-item'));

    $item->setJQueryParams(array(
        'source' => $some URL , 
        'minLength' => '1'));
```

The javascript generated by the viewHelper will be :

```
$("#auto-item").autocomplete({"source":"some URL","minLength":"1"});
```

the last line is the target

Answer (score 0):

Say you wanted to look-up a customer.  Your source endpoint could be an action on a controller perhaps dedicated to serving autocomplete data.

Main thing to be aware of is format of the expected data:
`[{"id":123,"label":"Some Customer","value":"Some Customer (ID#123)"},...`

The 'label' and 'value' give you a chance to show alternate strings for the drop down list and what is ultimately selected.

Here is an example.

```
class Service_AutocompleteController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    /**
     * The query / q for the auto completion
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_term;

    /** 
     * @see Zend_Controller_Action::init()
     */
    public function init()
    {       
        $this->_term = (isset($this->_request->term)) ? $this->_request->term : null;
    }

    /**
     * Serve up JSON response for use by jQuery Autocomplete
     */
    public function customerLookupAction()
    {
        // Disable the main layout renderer
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

        // Do not even attempt to render a view
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

        $query = "
                    SELECT  TOP 50
                            c.id                            AS id,  
                            c.name + '(ID#' + c.id + ')'    AS label,                           
                            c.name                          AS value
                      FROM  customer c
                     WHERE  $label LIKE ?
                  ORDER BY  c.name";

        $db = Zend_Registry::get(SOME_DB_ADAPTER);
        $results = $db->fetchAll($query, array('%' . $this->_term . '%'));      

        echo Zend_Json::encode($results);
    }
}
```

Sometimes people take this a little further and have a view helper to send back the JSON, you could remove some of the repeated code in the controller actions that way.

Answer (score 0):

Juste put this in your view file :

```
$this->jQuery()->getOnLoadActions()
```

it returns the javaScript generated by the jQuery helper